# How to upload an Azure Management Certificate using the Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-management-api, azure-cli

Is it possible to upload an Azure Management Certificate using the Azure Powershell or Azure CLI?

Background: My goal is to write a script that'll let me log into Azure using my Microsoft credentials, and then once I'm authenticated to Azure it'll let me upload a management cert to each of my subscriptions.

Then in the future I'll be able to manage my subscriptions using that cert I uploaded and not have to worry about logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Add-AzureCertificate -ServiceName "ContosoService" -CertToDeploy ContosoCertificate.pfx -Password "password"
```

[Found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/add-azurecertificate?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)